# Does cssnano apply css autoprefixer?

Tags: css, gulp, autoprefixer, cssnano

I want to apply cssnano and autoprefixer on my css code. 
I read on the internet that it is enough to use cssnano, that cssnano automatically applies autoprefixer. When I use this code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');

gulp.task('default', function() {
return gulp.src('./....css')
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./....'));
});
```

The css code is compressed but I dont see anywhere the prefixes. Does cssnano apply autoprefixer or not? Is the above code correct?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You require `gulp-autoprefixer`

```
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('default', function() {
return gulp.src('./....css')
  .pipe(cssnano({
        autoprefixer: {
           browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'Firefox >= 20'],
           add: true
        }
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./....'));
});
```

Also, in the array `{browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'Firefox >= 20']}` you can pass any version depending on your use.